# Упала процессорная мощность на сервере, в чем может быть дело?

Tags: linux, debian

Со вчерашнего дня (с 11:30) резко упала доступная процессорная мощность на VDS (хостится в Ру-Центре), в чем может быть дело? Никаких кардинальных изменений не проводилось, все работало в штатном режиме. После этого появились тормоза, а скрипты стали отрабатывать в 5-10 раз медленнее.

[image: munin]
А это вывод с top и сетевая активность.

[image: top]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**UPD**

На Тостере знающие люди высказали следующие идеи: https://toster.ru/q/426183

Кто что думает по поводу этих комментариев?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58946/discussion-on-question-by-dmitry-maslennikov-----).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему хостинг-провайдер проводил не совсем честную виртуализацию VPS. Пришлось перенести все к другому провайдеру.